# browsing sub directories using _finddata_t->name

Tags: c, visual-c++, if-statement, struct, subdirectory

I use visual studio 2010 for windows XP. This function is used to print all sub directory but I'm faced to terrible problem. See following code:

```
typedef struct _finddata_t FILE_SEARCH;

void fileListPrint(char* path, FILE_SEARCH* file_search, int deep){ 
intptr_t h_file;
int i, isForD;
char cwd[256];
char* temp = path;  
FILE_SEARCH fileSearch;

temp = (char*)malloc(256);

for(i=0; i<strlen((path)); i++)
{
    temp[i] = path[i];
}
temp[i-3] = '\0';


if((h_file = _findfirst(path, file_search)) == -1L)
    errorHandling("doesn't exist file\n");


printf("[%s] 출력 [%d] 깊이 \n", path, deep);
do
{       
    printf("%s\n", file_search->name);              
    isForD = isFileOrDir(strncat(temp, file_search->name,sizeof(temp) + sizeof(file_search->name)));        
    printf("%d\n", isForD);

    temp[i-3] = '\0';       

    if(file_search->name == ".")
        printf("same\n");
    else
        printf("diff\n");

    if(0 == isForD)
    {                   
        strncat(temp, "\\*.*", sizeof(temp) + 5);
        Sleep(1000);
        fileListPrint(temp, &fileSearch, deep+1);                       
        temp[i-3] = '\0';       }
    else if(1 == isForD)
    {
        temp[i-3] = '\0';       
        continue;
    }
    else if(file_search->name == ".")
    {
        temp[i-3] = '\0';       
        break;
    }



}while(_findnext(h_file, file_search) == 0);

_findclose(h_file);

free(temp);
}
```

I'm trying to understood to this code snippet:

```
 if(file_search->name == ".")
        printf("same\n");
    else
        printf("diff\n");
```

Why it is not same?

print print result this :

```
[D:\*.*] 출력 [0] 깊이
.
0
diff
[D:\1\*.*] 출력 [1] 깊이
.
0
diff
[D:\1\.\*.*] 출력 [2] 깊이
.
0
diff
[D:\1\.\.\*.*] 출력 [3] 깊이
.
0
diff
```

infinite loop.

How I should solve this issue?

Comment: file_search->name == "." My version of C does not allow string comparison with ==. Maybe you want strcmp() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(file_search->name == ".")
```

My version of C does not allow string comparison with ==. Maybe you want strcmp() ?